# Read Env Variable in Crontab

Tags: bash, cron

I want to read a env variable in crontab.

I tried with run printenv from crontab and it runs fine:

```
* * * * * BASH_ENV=/etc/profile bash -c "printenv CNE_CLUSTER_NAME  >> output.txt"
```

I need to run a job with some operation performed by python's script. I sheduled it in crontab like this:

```
* * * * * BASH_ENV=/etc/profile bash -c "/usr/bin/python3 /var/cne/cluster/$(echo $(printenv CNE_CLUSTER_NAME))/scripts/setup/job.py"
```

But when running from crontab is var CNE_CLUSTER_NAME is empty

```
python3: can't open file '/var/cne/cluster//scripts/setup/job.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory)
```

So, how can i do to read variable or replaced the values's variable in the string  ? Please.

Comment: Environment variables are local to each process (although subprocesses inherit copies of their parent process's environment), and cron jobs normally run with a very minimal environment. How is `CNE_CLUSTER_NAME` supposed to get set in this job's environment? Also, you shouldn't use `echo $(somecommand)` -- the `echo` and the `$( )` basically cancel each other out, so it's equivalent to just running `somecommand` directly, just less efficient and with some potential for parsing weirdness.

Comment: And what is the solution  or recommendations? Because i need something that helps me to trigger the script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `printenv` to acces the value of `CNE_CLUSTER_NAME`.

```
* * * * * BASH_ENV=/etc/profile bash -c '/usr/bin/python3 /var/cne/cluster/$CNE_CLUSTER_NAME/scripts/setup/job.py'
```

`$CNE_CLUSTER_NAME` is passed literally, and the shell that executes the command will expand the parameter to the value found in its environment.

Comment: It is passing  an empty value too,  if i pass as you say. When i used printenv , it prints the value for that env variable.

Comment: @PeterWegner90 If I understand what's going on, this should work. Are you using it *exactly* like this, especially including using single-quotes instead of double-quotes? If it really doesn't work like this, you need to tell us more about what's going on, especially where `CNE_CLUSTER_NAME` is being defined.